# Android Studio - ¿ Por qué falla mi selección de un ítem de un Spinner?

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, adapter

**Descripción:**

Tengo un **Spinner** el cual permite a los usuarios seleccionar su país de residencia mediante una lista de ítems.

**Adjunto el código XML de los ítems de mi spinner:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_bandera"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/perfil"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_pais"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:text="@string/argentina"
    android:textColor="#252525"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img_bandera"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/img_bandera"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img_bandera" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Adjunto foto de los items de mi spinner**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, el primer ítem dice "País" y no posee bandera. Esto se debe a que programé el adaptador para que la posición 0 del array del spinner haga desaparecer la bandera y cambie el formato del texto.

**Adjunto el código del adapter que realiza esta situación:**

```
private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dropdown_spinner_localidad,parent,false);
    }

    ImageView img_bandera = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_bandera);
    TextView txt_pais = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pais);

    model_spinner_localidad currentItem = getItem(position);

    if(position == 0){
        img_bandera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txt_pais.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A3A3A3"));
        txt_pais.setText(currentItem.getNombre_pais());
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.leftMargin = 100;
        txt_pais.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    else if(position >= 1){
        Glide.with(context).load(currentItem.getUrl_bandera()).placeholder(R.drawable.img_loading).error(R.drawable.img_error).dontAnimate().into(img_bandera);
        txt_pais.setText(currentItem.getNombre_pais());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Esto es así porque es la forma en la que quiero que se vean los ítems. El problema está en que cuando elijo una opción del spinner, la opción seleccionada toma la propiedad de la **"Posición 0"** y no se por que.

**Adjunto el código de model:**

```
public class model_spinner_localidad{
String url_bandera, nombre_pais;

public model_spinner_localidad(String url_bandera, String nombre_pais) {
    this.url_bandera = url_bandera;
    this.nombre_pais = nombre_pais;
}

public String getUrl_bandera() {
    return url_bandera;
}

public void setUrl_bandera(String url_bandera) {
    this.url_bandera = url_bandera;
}

public String getNombre_pais() {
    return nombre_pais;
}

public void setNombre_pais(String nombre_pais) {
    this.nombre_pais = nombre_pais;
}
}
```

**Adjunto foto de como se ve el item seleccionado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Me gustaría que esto deje de pasar. Quiero que solamente la posición 0 (el ítem que dice "País" el cual no debe contener bandera) conserve dichas propiedades**

Gracias por leer!

Comment: ¿ El primer elemento del Array tiene como nombre "País" ?

Comment: Exactamente Jorge. Espero me puedas ayudar con esto ! :c

Comment: Puedo ver que tiene model_spinner_localidad  @TomasM

Comment: @Jorgesys Actualizé la respuesta!

Comment: para que usas esta linea model_spinner_localidad currentItem = getItem(position);

Comment: @GastónSaillén es una referencia a la clase model mediante el cual puedo acceder a los valores de tipo String que hay dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que tengas tu spinner con los datos, simplemente desde tu UI podes usar `setOnItemSelectedListener`, esto te va a permitir clicar por cada item que hayas llenado en el adaptador del spinner

Este listener te va a devolver una position para que puedas acceder a cada elemento que llenaste en el adaptador del spinner

```
tu_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
tu_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String pais = tu_spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                Log.d("Pais seleccionado : ",pais);
                 }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```